# Set return URL after password is set

Tags: users, config

When I add a new user in the admin area, they get a link to activate their account. On the screen that link goes to, they are prompted to set a password. After the password is submitted, they are returned to `/dashboard`. How do I alter that return? I have the following config variables set

```
'useEmailAsUsername' => true,
'autoLoginAfterAccountActivation' => true,
'activateAccountSuccessPath' => 'members/index',
```

Answer (score 3):

Solved this by

- creating the [Set Password form](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/set-password-form) in a template with the correct
  return
- setting it's path with [setPasswordPath](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#setPasswordPath)
- setting a path for    [setPasswordSuccessPath](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#setPasswordSuccessPath) to catch *forgot password*
  resets

Answer (score 0):

The currently logic around that is "if the account has Access the CP permissions, send them to the control panel login page, otherwise, send them to wherever the `activateAccountSuccessPath` config setting is set to".

Since you've got `autoLoginAfterAccountActivation` set, the CP login page redirects to the CP dashboard.

If that's not the behavior you're looking for, you can create a plugin that mimics the necessary `craft/app/controllers/UsersControllers` methods changing the logic for your requirements as necessary.

Comment: Thanks Brad. This member group didn't have CP access. Seems like they should have gone to activateAccountSuccessPath - but they weren't. I x-posted with you what worked for me, it's probably better to deliver my own form anyway.